# Windows NTFS filesystem - user cannot access file using Administrators group permissions

Tags: windows, file-permissions, file-sharing, ntfs

There is a shared folder on the computer running Windows 2012R2 with a NTFS filesystem.

There is a local User X who is part of the local Group Administrators on the computer.

The Shared folder is configured like this for Sharing permissions and local Security permissions:

- Sharing -> Permissions -> Full control for User X
- Security -> Full control for Group Administrators (no reference to User X)

The issue is that when connecting via a remote computer (Windows 10) using network file sharing and User X credentials, User X can access the files in the Shared folder (read) but it unable to edit them (write, modify, delete).

There is no reference to User X in the folder/file permissions (neither allow or deny) but since User X is part of Group Administrators and Group Administrators has Full control permissions for the Shared folder, why can't User X modify the files?

Comment: The local administrators group behaves weirdly when it comes to file permissions. I have run into issues before when the user was granted permission to "just" that group instead of a dedicated one. However that was on the server directly, not over the network

Answer (score 0):

Check to what the permissions apply: Open properties on the folder, switch to the security tab and klick advanced. Select your admin group and klick edit. Check what is selected on `Applies to:`
[image]

Also check the inheritance (marked green in the picture). If it is disabled, you might want to enable it. This will rewrite all subfolders permissions with this ones.

Comment: Administrators group has full access and inheritance is also enabled, still can’t write or modify or delete files. If I use a different group with the same permissions it works but it won’t for Administrators group.